# Apache Storm Multilang: Purpose of ReadTasksIds

Tags: apache-storm

I have been attempting to use Storm's Multilang Protocol for a project. I've read through the [protocol](https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Multilang-protocol.html) and for the most part it makes sense. Looking over the python multilang source code I've noticed that in the emit method after emitting a tuple, it calls a readTaskIds() method.

```
def emit(*args, **kwargs):
    __emit(*args, **kwargs)
    return readTaskIds()
```

On the [concepts page](https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Concepts.html#stream-groupings), it mentions that using directGrouping() you are able to send your output to a specific task. And lines 124-129 of [JsonSerializer](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/0c2b3a4f640d1b2905c093eb85f03190ceb0a711/storm-core/src/jvm/backtype/storm/multilang/JsonSerializer.java) (which handles multilang communication) it's checking to see if a "need_task_ids" field is present and will not send the taskids only if it's defined as false in the json.

So I'm wondering if anyone can explain/confirm for me why Storm needs the TasksIds? There's nothing in the multilang protocol that mentions it. Is it only for the use case of wanting to send tuples to a specific task using directGrouping()? Or is there any benefit to having it? Adding a "need_task_ids" field in my json would be pretty easy to stop this from happening (if I understand it correctly), but I don't know if there are any downsides in doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with multilang protocol. However, you explanation meets my experience in using Storm's low level Java API. In this API, you either specify task-ids in case of a direct stream or no task-ids in case of other groupings (eg, shuffle, field, all). Thus, I claim that your own explanation is correct. I also know some internal Clojure code which does exactly the same thing: it checks if task ids are provided. If not, it looks for the specified connection pattern, computes the task-ids, and returns them to the user code after sending the tuples.

Comment: Thanks for answering, do you have any idea why sending tasks ids is the default behavior even though directoryGrouping() is the only Stream Grouping that requires this?

Comment: Don't know... this in too deep into the internal design of the system. Sound like a design decision (for whatever reason). Maybe you can ask at `dev@storm.apache.org`